# Array to XML write object when key is numeric

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have a function who convert an array to XML but it doesn't work in any case.

```
public function array_to_xml($data, &$xml_data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            $key = 'item'.$key;
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
     }
}
```

But if I send this array it will returns `<item0...n>` :

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><offices></offices>');

$first = array("id" => 1, "name" => "firstOffice");
$second = array("id" => 2, "name" => "secondOffice");
$offices = array("office" => array($first, $second));

return array_to_xml($data, $xml);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<offices>
    <office>
        <item0>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>firstOffice</name>
        </item0>
        <item1>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>secondOffice</name>
        </item1>
    </office>
</offices>
```

How can I edit my function to get this result :

```
<offices>
    <office>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>firstOffice</name>
    </office>
    <office>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>secondOffice</name>
    </office>
</offices>
```

Actually I'll return JSON or XML based on the accept header then I have to use the same array for the JSON and the XML.

Here is a part of my current code :

```
public function getOffices() {
    $tools = new Tools();
    $accept = $this->request->getHeader('accept');
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><offices></offices>');

    $offices = Offices::find();  // Find all offices, I'm using Phalcon PHP ORM

    return $tools->formatAdapter($accept, array("office" => $offices->toArray()), 200, $xml);
}
```

**Tools functions class**

```
public function array_to_xml($data, &$xml_data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            $key = 'item'.$key;
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
     }
}

public function formatAdapter($type, $data, $code, &$xml_data) {
    if ($type == 'application/json') {
        return $this->JSONBuilder($data, $code);
    } else {
        $this->array_to_xml($data, $xml_data);
        return $this->XMLBuilder($xml_data->asXML(), $code);
    }
}

public function JSONBuilder($data, $code) {
    $response = new Response();

    $message = $this->getResponseDescription($code);

    $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->setStatusCode($code, $message);
    $response->setJsonContent($data);

    return $response;
}

function XMLBuilder($xml, $code) {
    $response = new Response();

    $message = $this->getResponseDescription($code);

    $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    $response->setStatusCode($code, $message);
    $response->setContent($xml);

    return $response;
}
```

**Edit formatAdapter function**

```
public function formatAdapter($type, $data, $code, &$xml_data, $loop = false) {
    if ($type == 'application/json') {
        return $this->JSONBuilder($data, $code);
    } else {
        if ($loop) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($value as $obj) {
                    $this->array_to_xml(array($key => $obj), $xml_data);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->array_to_xml($data, $xml_data);
        }
        return $this->XMLBuilder($xml_data->asXML(), $code);
    }
}
```

It works if I add this loop inside my function and $loop parameter. But as you can see I have 2 foreach loops. It's possible to avoid the first foreach loop ? Because I'll loop once everytime. I tried with array_value() but there it doesn't work.

**EDIT FIX**

Finally I found a solution for my formatAdapter function, but it will works just for the first object. If someone has a better solution :

```
public function formatAdapter($type, $data, $code, &$xml_data, $loop = false) {
    if ($type == 'application/json') {
        return $this->JSONBuilder($data, $code);
    } else {
        if ($loop) {
            $key = key($data);
            foreach ($data[$key] as $obj) {
                $this->array_to_xml(array($key => $obj), $xml_data);
            }
        } else {
            $this->array_to_xml($data, $xml_data);
        }
        return $this->XMLBuilder($xml_data->asXML(), $code);
    }
}
```

Thanks to @iainn

Comment: not sure I understand the question. instead of the first output you are interested to get the second output?

Comment: Yes. item0, item1 is not explicit. I need to specify the object name. Here I have an array of offices then I want to write `<office>` for each offices

Comment: but you are running 'foreach' $key = 'item'.$key; ...?

Comment: Yep I have to replace this line by the previous key but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the existing function, then you can use the following:

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><offices></offices>');

$first = array("id" => 1, "name" => "firstOffice");
$second = array("id" => 2, "name" => "secondOffice");

array_to_xml(array("office" => $first), $xml);
array_to_xml(array("office" => $second), $xml);

echo $xml->asXML();
```

The function assumes that if you only pass in a single array, you want them grouped into itemX tags. If you want separate office tags, you need to call the function more than once with each office.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to loop and call array_to_xml because I made a function who returns XML or JSON then I have to send just one array. Then JSON and XML use the same array. Maybe I have to create another function when I'm in this case ?

Comment: Maybe I can add a foreach loop inside my `formatAdapter` function for the XML and a parameter `$loop` true / false

Comment: I adapted your solution in my function and it works for JSON and XML. Thanks. But it will not works if I have to loop on another subnode